# Check Excel column names with SQL Server 2008 column names

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, excel

Currently I'm writing a ASP.NET upload_module which uploads CSV files to a SQL Server 2008 database.

Is it possible to compare the column names of an excel file with those in a SQL Server database?

I need this because I want to check first if all columns are in the right order before I upload the file. This will prevent that data is inserted in the wrong column.

Thx

Comment: http://www.filehelpers.com/ should be able to help you here. It's a solution used in many SO questions.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this document [Read Excel files from ASP.NET](http://www.aspfree.com/c/a/ASP.NET-Code/Read-Excel-files-from-ASPNET/).

After taking the column names you can use that to compare